# How to safely include model instance methods from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'm working on a gem which adds a feature to Rails models and which currently has the following structure:

```
# lib/my_gem/loader.rb

module MyGem
  module Loader
    def loader
      include I18nAttributes::InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :extend, MyGem::Loader
```

```
# lib/my_gem/instance_methods.rb

module MyGem
  module InstanceMethods
    def foo
      puts '-> foo from gem'
      bar                       # <-- HERE
    end

    def bar
      puts '-> bar from gem'
    end
  end
end
```

In a Rails model, the functionality is now added with:

```
# app/models/model.rb

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  loader
end
```

This gives the model instance access to the instance methods from the gem:

```
irb(main):001:0> m = Model.new
irb(main):002:0> m.foo
-> foo from gem
-> bar from gem
```

However, when the model implements it's own `bar`:

```
# app/models/model.rb

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  loader

  def bar
    puts '-> bar from model'
  end
end
```

The `bar` method from the model is shaded:

```
irb(main):001:0> m = Model.new
irb(main):002:0> m.foo
-> foo from gem
-> bar from model
```

None of the above is a surprise, but the risk of colliding methods should be avoided:

- Is there an alternative to the `bar`-line in the gem code above (marked with `HERE`) which assures the `bar`-method defined in the module is used even if the model defines it's own version of `bar`?
- Is there a better pattern which eliminates this risk?

Thanks for your hints!

---

**UPDATE**

A way to not pollute the model instance with internal methods from the gem would be a nested class:

```
# lib/my_gem/instance_methods.rb

module MyGem
  module InstanceMethods
    class Inernal
      def bar
        puts '-> bar from gem'
      end
    end

    def foo
      puts '-> foo from gem'
      Internal.new.bar
    end
  end
end
```

Would be quite handy in my case since the nested class can have it's own set of instance variables. What do you think, an acceptable pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is able to over-write your method and there's nothing you can do about it. This is fundamental to how inheritance works in Ruby. I'm not sure why you'd go out of your way to prevent such a thing even if it were possible.

The approach most gems take is to keep the footprint of your module as minimal as possible. That often means moving methods you'd normally have as private instance methods to another module so they don't end up polluting the target class:

```
module MyExtension
  module Stub
    def loaded
      include MyExtension::InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def bar
      MyExtension::Support.format(:bar)
    end
  end

  module Support
    def self.format(text)
      "#{text} from module"
    end
  end
end
```

That means only the methods defined in `Stub` are imported at the class level. The rest are loaded on demand.

Extend your base class:

```
class ModelBase
end

ModelBase.send(:extend, MyExtension::Stub)
```

Then use it in a derived class:

```
class MyModel < ModelBase
  loaded
end

MyModel.new.bar
```

There's still no way to avoid overrides.